# How to change labels for permissions?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have form:

```
class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=u'First name', required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=u'Last name', required=True)
    permissions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Permission.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super( NewUserForm, self ).__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        ctypes = ContentType.objects.filter(
            Q(app_label='articles') |
            Q(app_label='tags')
        )
        self.fields['permissions'].queryset = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__in=ctypes)

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

And in template permissions shows me labels something like this:

```
[] articles | article | Can change article
[] articles | article | Can delete article
[] articles | article | Can view article

[...]
```

How to change this labels? I want to get only (for example): "Can change article", maybe in other language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) and define a `label_from_instance` method.

```
class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s" % obj.name # e.g. 'Can change article'
```

Then use your field subclass in your form.

```
class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    permissions = MyModelMultipleChoiceField(Permission.objects.none(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    ...
```